Fantasy book with a giant crab that's almost a god and a floating cloud that's very powerful magically
In said book, it has a giant crab that's almost a god. Also it has a floating cloud that's sentient, very powerful magically and childlike and mischievous, personality-wise. I can vaguely remember a palace getting attacked by the populace and at some point they have to go ask the floating cloud to help them, but it's formed some kind of religion.
I remember the front cover had a picture that reminded me of Terry Pratchett, but it definitely wasn't him. I would love to know the name of this book, as I would love to read it again.

"a floating cloud that's sentiment" Did you mean sentient here? Also, in roughly which year did you read this?

You mean art in the style of Josh Kirby?

I think this is one or even two of the books in Hugh Cooks Chronicles of an Age of Darkness https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronicles_of_an_Age_of_Darkness
heres a blurb from no 7 The Wazir and the Witch -
The Hermit Crab, a being with powers at least equal to those of any wizard or sorcerer, dwelt on a small island in the harbour of Untunchilamon's capital city. The Crab took exception to the violent political disputes which had disturbed the peace of its domicile; to restore peace, the Crab commanded Justina and Varazchavardan to declare a truce and resolve their differences. This they did. Had they disobeyed, they would have been turned inside out by a wrathful Crab, therefore the matter of their compliance is scarcely a mystery. This is the true history of the final days of the rule of Justina Thrug upon the island of Untunchilamon, and it is the only such history which is worth the price of the fooskin upon which it is written. And remember: your historian was there.
Cant remember a sentient cloud, though there is a sentient mischivous colour changing sphere called Shabble
Check the wiki regarding the series - http://hughcook.wikidot.com/start

That's the beasty thank you
